# AJAX GET function using hyperlink?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use `AJAX GET`  function in my code instead of POST.

i have a few hyperlinks which look like this:

```
<a class=netro" href="mypage.php?search=dog"></a>
<a class=netro" href="mypage.php?search=cats"></a>
<a class=netro" href="mypage.php?search=donkey"></a>
<a class=netro" href="mypage.php?search=apples"></a>
```

and in mypage.php I have this:

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
$search = $_GET['search']; 

////rest of my code////

}
```

without AJAX, the page page works fine and it gets the results bases on `$search` properly.

but with AJAX, i get nothing back in response that I get from AJAX.

this is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $('.netro').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    var urlssg = "mypage.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: urlssg,
           dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
           success: function (response) {
                $("#col1").html(response);

                //alert('sent');
            }
         });
    });
});

});
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to put an opening quotation on your class attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `search` parameter along with the request. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.netro').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $a = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $a.attr('href'), // note that this will include the querystring param
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#col1").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfectly wrote... simply awesome.. Can you please explain me the meaning of `var $a = $(this);` ?

Comment: It's just used for storing the element which was clicked on to the `$a` variable. It's good practice to cache your selectors for better performance, although it wouldn't really make a difference here as it's only accessed once.

Comment: Thank You Sir. You meant to say `$(this);` is used to storing any element? Moreover, what do you mean by `cache your selectors` ?

Comment: `this` within a handler function is a reference to the element which was clicked on. using `$(this)` then puts that DOMElement in to a jQuery object. Caching a selector simply means to store it in a variable for quicker access when compared to having to query the DOM to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean, simple approach:

**HTML**

```
<a class="netro" id="dog">Dog</a>
<a class="netro" id="cats">Cat</a>
<a class="netro" id="donkey">Donkey</a>
<a class="netro" id="apples">Apples</a>
```

**JS/JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $(".netro").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sId = $(this).attr("id");
     $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "mypage.php?search="+sId ,
           data: { search: search_id },
           dataType: "html",              
           success: function (data) {
                //Do something with the response data....
            }
         });
    });
});
```